# Convert JSON to list of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I convert my JSON to a list of arrays

My JSON is Serie :

```
[{"Value":10,"ValuePourcent":2},{"Value":20,"ValuePourcent":3},{"Value":51,"ValuePourcent":1}]
```

I would like this format:

```
[[10,2],[20,3],[:51,1]]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
var linq = Enumerable.From(rows);

var Serie = linq
                .GroupBy("$.Year", null,
                    function(key, g) {
                        var result = {
                            Value: g.Sum("$.Car"),
                            ValuePourcent: g.Sum("$.CarPourcent")/Total*100,
                        };
                        return result;
                    })
                .ToArray()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try looping through the array, and converting the objects into arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `for` loop does the trick:

```js
var data = [
  {"Value":10,"ValuePourcent":2},
  {"Value":20,"ValuePourcent":3},
  {"Value":51,"ValuePourcent":1}
];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var datum = data[i];
  
  result.push([datum.Value, datum.ValuePourcent]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop through the json array like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse("[{\"Value\":10,\"ValuePourcent\":2},{\"Value\":20,\"ValuePourcent\":3},{\"Value\":51,\"ValuePourcent\":1}]");
var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    newArray.push([
        json[i].Value,
        json[i].ValuePourcent
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map

```
dataArray = [{"Value":10,"ValuePourcent":2},{"Value":20,"ValuePourcent":3},{"Value":51,"ValuePourcent":1}]

newFormat = dataArray.map(function(e){
                  return [e["Value"], e["ValuePourcent"]]
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [{"Value":10,"ValuePourcent":2},{"Value":20,"ValuePourcent":3},{"Value":51,"ValuePourcent":1}];
var data = $.parse(JSON(json))
var array = [];
var keys = Object.keys(json);
keys.forEach(function(key){
    array.push(json[key]);
    array.push(data[key]
});
```